# How do Mosfets and potentiometers work together?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, dc-motor, potentiometer, motor-controller

I am trying to control the speed of my motor with the circuit shown below:
[image]

The circuit works well, and I am able to control the speed. However, I don't understand why.

Here is my thinking now:

According to ohms law, V=RI, so when you change the resistance on the pot and you have fixed voltage, the current decreases.

I then assume that when the current decreases on a mosfet, then the voltage decreases because the angular velocity of a motor is directly proportional to voltage.

Is this correct?

Comment: Slightly offtopic but I feel that it should be mentioned - That is not how you should drive a motor. It is similar (but not equivalent) to driving a car and using the brake to go slower.

Comment: I would add a diagram to your quesiton. Not everyone wants to open a youtube video just to see a schematic... some can't at all due to various restrictions.

Comment: Is it any difference between potentiometer for sound system guitar to a dc motor usage? How many Ohm potentiometer is best for 3v DC motor (for my robotic) ? Please mention brand and specific ohm, many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MOSFET is connected as a "source follower" meaning that the voltage at the source (more or less) follows the voltage at the gate, minus a volt or three, depending on the type of MOSFET.

The potentiometer is connected as a voltage divider, across the source voltage, so it provides a voltage (relative to the '-' of the source, which I hereby dub "ground") that is (more or less) proportional to the angle of the wiper.

So the source voltage is a variable and relatively "stiff" voltage (meaning it doesn't change much with current). The motor is connected from that voltage to ground.

The motor is a permanent magnet DC brushed type. The torque is proportional to the rotor current. The rotor current, and therefore the torque, is proportional to the difference between the back-EMF of the motor and the applied voltage, so the motor speed is (more or less) constant with varying amounts of torque. (The back-EMF is proportional to the rotor RPM).

Say the winding resistance is 10 ohms. The stall current of the motor with 10V applied is thus 1A (and with 5V applied, 0.5A). As the motor speeds up, the back EMF increases, and thus the current and resulting torque drops,  until an equilibrium is established (even with no load on the shaft, a bit of torque is required to spin the motor due to friction and 'windage').

The back-EMF is just the voltage you would read on a voltmeter connected across the motor terminals if you spun the shaft at a certain RPM.

---

More efficient circuits would use a PWM rather than throwing away the power in the MOSFET. More accurate speed controls might measure the motor RPM and correct for changes, or would apply IR compensation (effectively inserting a bit of negative resistance to compensate for the resistance of the windings).

---

Note that normally one would like to see a catch diode across the motor, but it is unnecessary in this particular case.

Comment: if the potentiometer changes the voltage, and the voltage controls the speed, how does the mosfet play in?

Comment: The MOSFET acts as a current (not voltage) amplifier. The gate draws virtually no current, but the MOSFET can supply amperes. If you had a very low resistance potentiometer with the wiper connected directly to the motor it would be similar but would be drawing many, perhaps dozens of watts even with the motor not energized.

Comment: As soon as "the torque is proportional to the current", why the motor is inserted in the emitter to control it by voltage? Is it not better to put it into collector to control the torque by current?